# XAMPP - Apache could not start - Attempting to start Apache service

Tags: xampp

While trying to start Apache using XAMPP, I was receiving  - **"Attempting to start Apache service..."** message in XAMPP UI. No further details were available.

Where can I see the logs (I was running XAMPP as Admin) ?

[image: Apache - Fails to start]

Comment: In my case i found out that Skype was using the same port. Simply shutdown skype and it works. If ya open Xampp as admin and try to run again then it will provide you with the information of which program is occupying the port. If any at all that is.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I realized it was a port issue since I was running IIS and other web servers in my machine. But I was more interested to see a detailed error message with the port number in the UI.

Seems like it was not logged in the UI or log file (at least in my case), but in the Event viewer (Control panel -> View Event Logs). Under the **Even viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application**

I could see a permission error something like the below one:

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443

To fix this permission issue for SSL port, Please change the below line in **httpd-ssl.conf** (C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra)

```
 # When we also provide SSL we have to listen to the 
 standard HTTP port (see above) and to the HTTPS port

     Listen xxx
```

Replace XXX with any valid port number that is open in your machine

If you are having issues with Port 80, then change the **httpd.conf** file (C:\xampp\apache\conf)

```
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
 Listen 127.0.0.1:8000
```

I have also summarized other solutions that I came across:

1. Most often Skype blocks the Apache port. So terminate it and try again.
2. Find the process id (PID) that is using the Blocked port ( netstat -ano) and kill the corresponding process in Windows Task Manager.

Comment: Keep in mind that it's good practice to also change the line lower in httpd-ssl.conf `www.example.com:80` (replace 80 with the port you are using for httpd)

Comment: +1 for sharing the path in the event viewer (Even viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application) I wouldn't find it myself and helped me solve the issue.

Comment: You can find the **Event Viewer** easier by typing **`eventvwr`** in the Command Prompt.

Answer (score 46):

IF PORT 80 IS NOT THE ISSUE!

Check to see if the port 80 is in use first as this can be an issue.
You can do this by typing "netstat -an" into cmd. The look for 0.0.0.0:80 under Local Address, if you find this is in use then follow the solution from @Karthik. However, I had a similar issue but my port 80 was not in use.
My XAMPP had wrong paths locations, steps to fix this:

1.Find out the Apache version you are using, you can find this by looking in Services (Control panel, Admin Tools, Services) and finding Apache in my case it was listed as Apache2.4

2.Close XAMPP.

3.Run cmd as admin.

4.execute 'sc delete "Apache2.4"' (put your version in place of mine and without the surrounding ' ', but with the " " around Apache).

5.execute 'sc delete "mySQL"', again remove the '' when you type it.

6.reopen XAMPP and try starting Apache

If you are having trouble with FileZill, Mercury, or Tomcat you could try it here too, but I have not tested that myself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is a _netstat_ button on the right side of xampp control window as well if you wanted

Answer (score 22):

For those who have accidentally (or not) changed one of the .conf files and apache does not run even after trying all the above solutions.

One easy way to track where the issue is located, is to run Apache via command prompt:

(On windows) : open command prompt as admin then navigate inside the bin folder of Apache , next run

`httpd` in order to run apache

> C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd

For my case it was :

[image: apache via cmd]

someone had added a virtual host in the specific file that caused the problem . I commented the lines and Apache ran fine.

Comment: httpd -t will check your config files for any syntax errors. this can be quite usefule

Answer (score 9):

start xampp (as administrator), 
(1) right click C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe, and run as administrator.
(2) unistall service module and then install service module.
(3) now try start the apache and mysql.

Answer (score 3):

Check your DocumentRoot path (in `httpd.conf`); a typo there can cause this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue while updating to PHP7.2

**Problem:**
First I closed skype and then checked whether port 80 is not an issue. How you can check that? See @AlexT comment above.

In my case, port 80 wasn't an issue. So now I had to figure out what was wrong. So I checked Error Logs **Control Panel > Even viewer > Windows Logs > Application** and found following error against Apache2.4

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 520 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 18 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll into server: The Apache service named is not a valid Win32 application.

Which means I had installed wrong PHP version. Actually I downloaded win64 version while the required version was Win32 for me.

So I downloaded correct version from: [Download PHP 7.2.0](http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.3) extracted it in **C:/xampp/php** folder, restarted the apache and it worked :)

Comment: This helped me. I had done the same thing. You'd think it would be written somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but it was because I had a previous version of xampp already installed and I tried to install a newer version. I had installed the newer version in another file directory (I had named the file directory xampp2). I solved the problem by uninstalling the newer version, renaming the old one (I renamed it xamppold) and I installed xampp again.

I guess if you haven't installed   xampp in another file directory , it should be enough to reinstall xampp. If you are worried about your files , you always can make a backup before reinstalling xampp.

I solved the problem after watching the xampp activity log (the list of the bottom) and realizing xampp was trying to open the custom file path but I had another route path. If the first option didn't work, at least you can scroll up in the activity log and see what's error you get while starting as admin and trying to re install the Apache module or trying to start the module.

You may wander why I didn't just simply uninstall the whole thing from the beginning , and the answer would be because I had to tweak a couple of things in xampp for some different projects (from changing the ports , to add .dll to run mongo.db in Apache), and I was just too lazy to re-do everything again :b

I hope my answer can be helpful for anyone since this is my first time writing in stackoverflow :)

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, executing "setup_xampp.bat" in xampp folder solved my issue.

Comment: Thank you mate. this works for me. i had no config and port issue. I tried it as a last resort your answer. This saved me from reinstalling the whole windows. since i changed my pc HD to another pc and this was the issue. you are a savior !

Answer (score 1):

In my case, with the same problem and Xampp window, I had copied *\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf* entries from an old Xampp version to a newly installed one so I could continue to open local projects in browsers. One of the vhosts paths was wrong. After deleting that entry Apache started without problem.

The reference by @Karthik to *"in the Event viewer (Control panel -> View Event Logs"* saved me time. It's all too easy to presume Xampp logs will point to the problem. It doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Also check if your xampp is installed in the main directory like C or D or E and not in or within a folder of that directory? i.e. ( "D:/Xampp" or is it "D:/something/Xampp") if its not in the main path of the directory, it will show this error.

copy your xampp directory from "D:\Something\Xampp"  to  "D:"
So it becomes like this "D:\Xampp"
and the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reason.

1. 443 port or 80 port are used in another application.
   For example, VM is using 443.
   If you use VM, please change xampp 443 port to another port in httpd-ssl.conf file.
2. documentroot
   if there is not index.php or index.html in DocuementRoot, Xampp does not work.
   You can search and change DocumentRoot in httpd.conf file.
   This is my experience.
   Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Starting Xampp as a console application (simply by doubleclicking xampp_start.exe in the Xampp root folder) was the only thing that worked for me on Windows 10 (no Skype, no Word Wide Web Publishing Service). WampServer and UwAmp also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My scenario was different after I tested all the possible options. If you have changed the ports and still get the same problem, well here's something you can try out. This was done in Windows 7.

**Step 1:** Confirm the cause of the error by going to Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application -> Error. Mine said "The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 424 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load c:\xampp\php\php5apache.dll into server: The specified module could not be found." So I needed to change \php5apache.dll to the version of my php and apache version installed which was php7apache2_4.dll

**Step 2:** To get the correct name for your .dll php and apache file, got to C:\xampp\php. You will see something like php7apache2_4.dll with other files in the folder.

**Step 3:** Go to C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf and edit the configuration file and change "c:\xampp\php\php5apache.dll" to "c:\xampp\php\php7apache2_4.dll" in my case. Make sure you open the file as administrator save changes made.

**Step 4:** Run the xampp server and everything should work fine. Do not forget to shut down the xampp server before doing the changes to the apache configuration file.

Hope this helps. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard-coded IP in httpd.conf and my local IP had changed which was causing my issue, changed IP over and all worked again

Answer (score 0):

Try to install x86 version of XAMPP. The default XAMPP version on their website is x64 (maybe because I'm using x64 Windows 7).
[download link here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.3.2/)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I installed under Program Files, which they do not recommend due to write issues. This might only be a problem if you are not logged in as an admin and use a password to install. I just uninstalled and installed in a directory that did not need admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Apache didn't get Disabled in Services (Control panel, Admin Tools, Services).  If it's Disabled then Set it to Manual and it should run.  That was my case, I found Apache Disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for my particular scenario (It had been working a couple days before getting borked):

Port 80 was not the problem, but something I had done while messing around with **Services** and Startup.

1. Type `msconfig` on Windows' Start menu
2. Click System Configuration

[Screenshot for System Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEgmw.png)

3. In the **Services** tab, search for Apache24 (Click "Hide all Microsoft services" in the checkbox at the bottom of the window to make it easier to find)
4. If its checkbox isn't checked, check it

If it was already checked, then this guide isn't going to help. However if it is:

5. Click OK, your PC will have to restart
6. Try once again! In my case Apache was already running once I opened Xampp

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.Just click on services button.Then find apache and right cick > properties > set startup type as Automatic/ Manual. Now close apache and try again.It will work!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me it wasn't a port or service issue; I had to re-run the XAMPP setup script. Although this didn't directly fix the issue for me, the script was much more verbose than the XAMPP log, pointing me in the right direction to actually solve the problem.

From the XAMPP GUI, click on *Shell*, type `set`, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete to the `setup_xampp.bat` file, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run it.

In my case I got the following output:

```
[ERROR]: Test php.exe failed !!!
[ERROR]: Perhaps the Microsoft C++ 2008 runtime package is not installed.
[ERROR]: Please try to install the MS VC++ 2008 Redistributable Package from the Mircrosoft page first
[ERROR]: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582
```

This particular error is misleading. Although it specifies the Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package, PHP 7.4.x requires the [Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable Package](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2019).

After installing that and following the prompt to restart, sure enough I'm now able to start Apache as normal.

Answer (score 0):

make sure no space in front of the port number if you ever edited it.

Answer (score 0):

From Xampp control panel, click on config (next to Apache), then choose Apache(`httpd.config`), search for `listen 80` and change the port to another port.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works with you, I would suggest you download **MAMP** and use it instead.

It does the same thing, if not better.

[image: Here are the port infos]

Answer (score 0):

Comment this lines from `httpd.conf`:

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

In the case you're using them it may solve.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to debug Apache errors by running the command line,

on windows, click on shell then type httpd

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

when i run xampp control panel normal:

[image]

I had been run

I can’t start apache
So, I will run it with administrator:

[image]

I can run apache