# XAMPP on Windows - Attempting to start Apache service... - No Port block

Tags: windows, apache, dll, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on my windows 7 machine but can't get Apache to work.

After opening the XAMPP panel and installing Apache service: I have tried start it, it always get stuck at "Starting apache service..."

On start I get the following:

```
7:36:57  [main]     Initializing Modules
7:36:57  [main]     The MySQL module is disabled
7:36:57  [main]     The FileZilla module is disabled
7:36:57  [main]     The Mercury module is disabled
7:36:57  [main]     Starting Check-Timer
7:36:57  [main]     Control Panel Ready
7:37:02  [main]     Executing "services.msc"
7:41:50  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache service...
```

**Event Viewer:**

The Apache service named

reported the following error: >>> 
   httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 172 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: The specified module could not be found.

I also get an ERROR for the **.NET Runtime Optimization Service**:

.NET Runtime Optimization Service (clr_optimization_v2.0.50727_32) - Failed to compile: PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 . Error code = 0x80070002
   PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

On the first start i had some .dll problems but i solved them, I do not know if it is related.

I already tried everything in: 
"[XAMPP - Apache could not start - Attempting to start Apache service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069857/xampp-apache-could-not-start-attempting-to-start-apache-service)"
without improvement.

Any advice on how I could resolve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Go to Xampp control panel and click on config->httpd.conf then go to line no 171 and change 
    ServerName localhost:80
    with
    ServerName localhost:81
It will work.