# phpMyAdmin not connecting when I log in to index.php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I can connect to the login screen but when I log in I get

This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.

I am using XAMPP and SecureWAMP if that matters.

Comment: Make sure that MySQL is started correctly. You could also try and restart it if it already is running. Btw, why are you running both XAMPP and SecureWAMP?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Because half of the stuff on XAMPP and half the stuff on SecureWAMP aren't working, is it a huge problem? Also, restarting didn't help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, in case my answer posted below helps you out and solves your problem, do not forget to mark the answer as correct by clicking the tickmark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might happen because of MySQL not properly getting started because of locked files from the previous session of your XAMPP running.

To fix this:

```
1. stop your MySQL from XAMPP Control panel,
2. go to your XAMPP installation folder
3. then go to mysql>data
4. and delete iblogfile0 and iblogfile1
5. start MySQL from XAMPP control panel.
```

Should work now.

Comment: I've already tried this and it fixed a previous issue, but no success here. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37838225/10203085 It turns out Apache wasn't working correctly, I followed the instructions from this dude, and it worked fine.